# How to get exact special characters trough Mule HTTP listener

Tags: java, http, mule, special-characters

I am using Mule 3.6.1 CE. I am trying to post "*Box 83 ållebergsvägen 4*" string trough inbound http connector and trying to log it. But what I get logged is "*Box 83 ÃƒÂ¥llebergsvÃƒÂ¤gen 4* ".

How could we get log exact same string which has posted.

Are there any configurations to be made in http listener configurations? or do I have to use a header parameter in postman?

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding with UTF-16 or UTF-32

```
<set-property propertyName="MULE_ENCODING" value="UTF-16" doc:name="Property" />
```